# ProcessShellCommand OpenFile calls OpenDocumentFile before document or view class are constructed

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a single document MFC project with the document/view architecture. In the source file for the class derived from CWinApp, let's call it CMyApp, in the CMyApp::InitInstance there is this part of the initialization code:

```
CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);

// Dispatch commands specified on the command line.  Will return FALSE if
// app was launched with /RegServer, /Register, /Unregserver or /Unregister.
if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
        return FALSE;
```

In my CMyApp class I have overridden the OpenDocumentFile function. Then I give the debugger command line a full file path and name. I set a break on the call to ProcessShellCommand, and it has the file name and the m_nShellCommand to OpenFile. The ProcessShellCommand first calls the OpenDocumentFile function that I have overridden, as intended, but the problem is the CMyDocument and CMyView class haven't been constructed yet. How does MFC expect me to open a document if it hasn't even constructed the class yet? I can do this and it works but just seems like I am not doing things as intended.

```
CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo, cmdInfo2;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);
// Dispatch commands specified on the command line.  Will return FALSE if
// app was launched with /RegServer, /Register, /Unregserver or /Unregister.
if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo2))
    return FALSE;
if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
        return FALSE;
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: What's the issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to learn the "proper" way to open a file from the command line

Comment: ...and read the contents into member variables of my CMyDocument class.

Comment: What's the reason that you believe that this weren't happening?

Comment: I would assume that ProcessShellCommand would instantiate the Document class at least before trying to open a document specified on the command line. Why would it try to open the document first? How are you supposed to read the document and fill out the document class if it isn't even instantiated?

Comment: The CCommandLineInfo object is passed to [CWinApp::ProcessShellCommand]() to handle the command-line arguments and flags. When the command line parameter is `CCommandLineInfo::FileOpen`, the OpenDocumentFile() function is called. Whether it is CWinApp::OnFileNew() or CWinApp::OpenDocumentFile(), the final call is the `CSingleDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile()` function. In this function, first call the CDocTemplate::CreateNewDocument() function to create a document.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to see what it actually does? Visual Studio comes with one of the best debuggers you'll find. Make sure to get confident using it. Alternatively, work through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/document-templates-and-the-document-view-creation-process).

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Can you give an example? I have been unable to make this work. I can call CreateNewDocument, but how do I make it THE CMyDoc object?